# How make CRUD of one to many in grocerycrud?

Tags: php, mysql, database, codeigniter, grocery-crud

I have tables  like this

**user**

```
id ,name
```

**user_email**

```
id ,user_id,email
```

user may have multiple emails.How can i do CRUD operation of these type of data in codeigniter grocerycrud?I tried [this](http://www.grocerycrud.com/examples/set_a_relation) but not working.

Comment: what you have tried so far post your effort

Comment: please read question. i given a link. i tried that.  i tried all documentation in official we website

Answer (score 0):

check this link hope this help you

http://www.grocerycrud.com/documentation/options_functions/set_relation

```
void set_relation( foriegn key , table that has the foriegn key, any needed column like title or date or what ever you need to retrieve else )
```